# Are there any established network quality classifications?

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, latency

I'm finishing a program that sends a lot of data over TCP/IP. I'd like to test it with various quality networks to measure how well it works under different conditions. Are there any established classifications for network quality based on bandwidth and latency?

Ideally I'd like a paper or website I can cite with something like:

```
Classification |  Bandwidth  | Latency | ...
--------------------------------------------
     High      |  10+ MB/s   | < 30ms  | ...  
     Medium    |   2  MB/s   | < 70ms  | ...
     ...
```

Comment: Nothing widely accepted, no.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton Do you know of any classifications (widely accepted or otherwise)?

Comment: https://help.netflix.com/en/node/306 is a decent starting point. Note that basically everyone just defines their own standards, though, and the netflix ones don't include latency (less relevant for them).